# pyyaml datetime.now() + timedelta

Tags: python, pyyaml, django-fixtures

I want to create fixtures in Django project. We are using fixtures to populate DB with test data. For some models.fields I need to set fresh date. For example:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=1)
```

but in pyyaml.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What is the desired output?

Comment: Why `relativedelta` and not `timedelta` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Because `timedelta` doesn't let you specify months, you have to give it days, and if you want to go a month forward, the number of days to go forward depends on what month you are in.

Comment: I know that with pyyaml we able to create `datetime` instances. But in fixture I need to set dynamic date and time. For example `subscription.expiration_date = now + 1 month`.